# Static Classes with C++

Tags: c++, oop, static-variables

Let me start by saying, I understand that "Static Classes" are not something that are used in C++, but I have a situation which I believe all information held by the class should be static. I am trying to understand if there is a better way to approach my problem.

**Example**: I am building a class to maintain information on my game's `window`, so I can access the current `window`'s `width` and `height` from any instance of the object. This class will be edited when I resize, minimize, maximize etc. My video game will never have two separate windows, only separate instances which should all contain the same data. Here is what I have:

---

**Window.h**

```
class Window {
    static int width;
    static int height;
public:
    Window();
    Window(int width, int height);
    static int getWindowWidth();
    static int getWindowHeight(); 
}
```

**Window.cpp**

```
#include "Window.h"

int Window::width = 0;    
int Window::height = 0;

Window::Window( ) { }

Window::Window(int window_width, int window_height) {

    width = window_width;        
    height = window_height;

    SDL_CreateWindow( "Window",
                       SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                       SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                       width,
                       height,
                       SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN
                    );
}

int getWindowWidth() {
    return width;
}

int getWindowHeight() {
    return height;
}
```

---

Using this method I am able to retrieve the `window`'s `width` as well as its `height` from any instance of the object.

However, it doesn't feel correct ( or elegant) because using this method, I now have to list every variable as `static` and each of these variable have to be initiated outside `Constructors` in my `.cpp` code ( and because your not supposed to have static classes in C++ ).

How can I access the `window`'s information from multiple instances without creating a static class?

*Thanks In Advance*

Comment: Er...why would all windows have the same width and height?

Comment: Why is it static?  That means every time you create a new window, you're going to be overwriting the width and height with whatever that window's dimensions are.  Width and height should be instance variables, and if anything needs access to them it can have them passed to it or it can get a const reference or const weak_ptr to your window object.

Comment: IMHO this is clearly an example of language features overkill. First of, each window must have its own height and width, second the minimum height and width could be just coded as 2 global consts.

Comment: I only create one window, therefore there is only one height and one width. They can't be coded as global constants because what happens if someone increases or decreases the size of the window?

Comment: This still isn't a good solution, because your code can freely create more than one window and you do nothing to restrict that.  A good rule is that an API should be *hard to use incorrectly* - this doesn't pass that test.  Make these variables instance variables and either allow multiple window instances or control window creation through a factory or a singleton.

Comment: I assumed this wasn't a good solution and that is why I asked the question ;). In future code, I will think of this rule ( hard to use incorrectly ). Thank you for the input.

Comment: Ship it! I think that once you need to modify this code again and add another, very similar, window you will come to understand why it is a bad idea. You can read as many books/blogs/comments as you like but if you don't understand how this will hinder you later then just use it. All will become clear to you when you once you need to maintain this code.

Comment: I am trying to create a video game. Can you please give me an example of why I would need add another window?

Comment: @Calvin It doesn't matter how many windows you'll have. You don't do static classes in c++ (and you don't need to). That's all.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you do not have an understanding of static variables, because this question does not make sense. The way you share static information is to declare variables static! This ensures that only one variable exists no matter how many instances of a class you create.

What you are looking for is a singleton, since you will only have one window. To do that, add this to your class:

```
class Window {
    Window(int width, int height);
    int width;
    int height;
public:
    static Window& getInstance();
    int getWidth() const {return width;} 
    int getHeight() const {return height;} 
}

static Window::Window& getInstance()
{
    static Window instance; 
    return instance;
}
```

Whenever you need a window, you will grab it using the getInstance() function. This will ensure that **only one window exists during the life of your program**.

Comment: I understand that you share static information with static variables. It just does not seem like sharing this information with a class is the _best_ method considering every variable of the class is going to be static.

Comment: Then you want a singleton. I will update my answer to show you how this is done.

Comment: The Singleton constructor should be private, not public (otherwise you can still construct Windows at will), and really it's cleaner to make width and height instance variables and make GetInstance() the only static method.

Comment: You still need to expose width and height via public accessors :)  I was saying that width and height should not be static and their accessors shouldn't be either.  Singletons should only differ from the design of normal classes in that only 1 instance can be created...  once you have a reference to the instance it should have a normal non-static interface.

Comment: Not done. This type of singleton is really ugly because it will be even more difficult to make it generic when you realize that you don't actually want a singleton. Please make the `width` and `height` regular non-static members.

Comment: getWidth() and getHeight() should be const.  Once that's implemented we can ship it.

Comment: Close, but I meant the methods should be const, not the return types.  Returning primitive types as const doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Please for the love of god do I have it right this time?

Comment: The proper syntax is `int getWidth() const {return width;}`  :)

Comment: @LawrenceAiello I don't see an obvious case that `Window` needs to be a Singleton. Just having a class, and passing it around whenever needed would merely suffice.

Comment: Ship it - that's a much cleaner singleton.

Comment: @LawrenceAiello I miss-spoke, I call additional `Windows` when I resize the screen. Therefore a singleton will not work. I do appreciate the answer and I am sure I will use this method in the future. Thanks.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ In my code right now, I pass `Window` around wherever it is needed, the problem I am having is that instances of `Window` other than the one in my `Listener` class or the class where it is originally called wont have access to the `Window`'s actual `width` and `height` unless `width` and `height` are static, is there another method for other instances to find the actual `width` and `height` of the current `Window`?